# Codename one list scrolled down when returning to form

Tags: ios, list, codenameone

I've had some testers reporting an intermittent issue on a search page that contains a list.
They say when they have been on the page and navigate to a sub page then return that the list is sometimes scrolled all the way to the bottom of the screen.
I've disabled tensile drag on the list, but I wanted to know if there was any other work-around for this issue?

Comment: Is this in a GUI builder app or a handcoded app? Also let me re-iterate: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/avoiding-lists.html

Comment: Made using the GUI builder.
This app is pretty far along in the dev cycle to fundamentally change the ui of a core screen.  
Is there a work around using lists?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with tensile drag. When you navigate from one form to another in the old GUI builder the form is re-created from scratch and re-positioned based on the data.

We try to select the previously selected item but if something in the list changed this might trigger issues.

You can override `restoreComponentState` in the state machine with a blank implementation to see that this is the cause of this behavior. Assuming that it is you can create a special case for the list instance.